# How to run PHP coming from a separate file

Tags: php, include

I have a form thats action is another page.

```
<form class="indexSearch" action="search.php" method="post">
```

to keep my code neat I'm keeping all my PHP code in a separate file that I am including in the head of every page...

```
<head>
    <?php include 'include/includes.php';?>
</head>
```

The problem I'm having is when the PHP code in the `includes.php` file runs, it echoes at the top left hand corner of the page I want it to appear on and I am confused about the best way to include it where I need it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thx

Sorry just to update on my question which was a bit vague in the include file I intend to hold all functions / scripts etc... the particular code I am trying to output in this instance is a while loops from a mysqli query

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that the PHP code in `includes.php` is displayed as it is?

Comment: What do you have in that file? Just variables or functions?

Comment: any change i can get a up vote as i can no longer post questions

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing echos in the include php, assign in to a variable and then echo it where you want it using:

```
    <?php echo $varname; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some conditions in your `include.php`

you can use functions such as `isset()`, `empty()` to protect them to print that by default.

and my personal suggestion is that use `require_once('include/include.php')`;

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php  include 'include/includes.php';  ?>
```

In includes.php:  define your values in to variable,

```
<?php $Variable = 'test check'; ?>
```

Now include your file where ever you want, after the inclusion of your `includes.php` you can able to retrive and print the value of `$Variable` .